# c# - Index out of range

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get the tweets from twitter.

Stored all the data into the database and then pass it to Siebel.

I get an error:

> Index was out of range

Below is the code:

```
 public void Call_Tweet_Update()
    {
        var service = new TwitterService(Consumer_Key, Consumer_Secret);
        service.AuthenticateWith(Access_Token, AccessToken_Secret);

        var tweets = service.ListTweetsOnHomeTimeline(new ListTweetsOnHomeTimelineOptions { Count = 200 });
        string[] twt_id = new string[50];
        long id = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int increment = 0;
        string twtid;
        string screenname;

        foreach (var tweet in tweets)
        {
            if (tweet.InReplyToStatusId.ToString() != "")
            {
                if ((tweet.User.ScreenName == "IIPL_LTD") || (tweet.Text.StartsWith("@IIPL_LTD")))
                {
   string replyid = tweet.InReplyToStatusId.ToString();

    while (replyid != "")
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            twt_id[i] = tweet.Id.ToString();
        }
        id = Convert.ToInt64(replyid);
        twtid = tweet.Id.ToString();

        i = i + 1;
        twt_id[i] = twtid;
        replyid = tweet.InReplyToStatusId.ToString();//Here I get an error
        increment = increment + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you may need to provide more code for us to be able to help you.

Comment: You code is incomplete. Where is defined twt_id?

Comment: What is the value of `i` initially? also have you stepped thru the code or did you just code and go..?? `twtid` where is that defined..? come on now

Comment: Why do you have so many ID values of differing types?  That makes us helping you and future maintenance rather difficult.

Comment: where has this array been defined twt_id[i]

Comment: Karl gave right answer. Can you change code by not using any hard coded size limits? It will help you here. Or, store data in round robin fashion, if the older data is not useful anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are asking for 200 tweets and you have only sized your string array to 50, so it blows up on the 51st tweet processed.

This code is the problem:

```
var tweets = service.ListTweetsOnHomeTimeline(
    new ListTweetsOnHomeTimelineOptions { Count = 200 });
string[] twt_id = new string[50];
```

Either change the number of tweets you are requesting or change the size of the string array to match the number of tweets requested.

UPDATE:

This logic is counter-productive, to say the least:

```
if (i == 0)
{
    twt_id[i] = tweet.Id.ToString();
}
id = Convert.ToInt64(replyid);
twtid = tweet.Id.ToString();

i = i + 1;
twt_id[i] = twtid;
```

You are adding the same tweet to two different indexes in your string array, change your code to this:

```
twt_id[i] = tweet.Id.ToString();
i = i + 1;
```

What is the purpose of `replyid = tweet.InReplyToStatusId.ToString();`, you are setting a value every loop iteration only to not use it anywhere, same with `id = Convert.ToInt64(replyid);` and `increment = increment + 1;`. You definitely need to clean up unused logic in your code.

Comment: still it is not working...

Comment: I have updated my answer and asked you some questions about your code.